# Skip code coverage and install code in production org

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I have got a project in salesforce that deals only with sObjects and custom objects. No classes or triggers. So what are the possible ways to package this and install it in production org since this cannot be subject to code coverage requirements? I'm aware that we cannot install packages without covering 75% of the code.

I'm trying to install an unlocked package and I'm using sfdx package commands to install the package in the org.

sfdx force:package:version:promote

this command fails to say that code coverage requirements are not met

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of package are you trying to install? How are you trying to install the package?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I've updated the question. Please check it

Comment: @Anjana, have you run the `force:package:version:create` with the `-c` flag? You don't need to have code coverage for non-existent code, but you might need to have used this flag.

Comment: @FelixvanHove Yes, I've used the -c flag. No use though. I don't have any unit tests because I don't have any classes or triggers. I just have custom objects

Comment: You can probably add a screenshot of the commands/error you are facing

Comment: I just tested this. If you use `-c` with no unit tests, it should still be promotable. What does your sfdx force:package:version:list output look like? Also, you didn't happen to "--skipvalidation", did you? Anything with skipped validation is not promotable.

Comment: Or try sfdx force:package:version:report -p 04t... I'd be interested in the output (without the IDs).

Comment: @sfdcfox. I'm not using --skipvalidation. I've added the screenshot of the commands

Comment: Okay, so you're using some kind of build tool. The problem might be with your script. I assure that, if everything is done correctly, code coverage is not an issue for a package with no code, so long as you use -c. Can you share your build script?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox your answers helped me. There was an error in the pipeline, nothing related to codecoverage issue